# Como verificar e adicionar um / em um caminho

Tags: php

Tenho um formulário onde o usuário vai digitar um determinado caminho, exemplo: /var/www... quero verificar se o usuário digitou uma / no final
exemplo /var/www/.../, ou seja se o ultimo carácter foi uma /, caso ele não tenha digitado fazer a inclusão da mesma, como faço isto em php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```
$caminho = $_POST['caminho'];
 // nisso ele pegará o último caracter do caminho e verificará se é uma barra,
 // se não for ele adicionará
$barra = substr($caminho, -1);
if ($barra != '/'){
    $caminho += '/';
}
```